# Active X error can't create object

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7, windows-server-2008

When I try to create object in classic ASP web page it gives the error Active X error can't create object. But in a vbs this object creation works fine. OS is Windows Server 2008 32 bit.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you allow to run 32-bit app.

IIS -> Application pools -> find yours one -> properties -> allow to run 32-bit app.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between vbs and asp is that vbs is executed on client under your current account and asp is on server under IIS account. Even client and server are on the same machine the account which you use to run asp on IIS is usually different with your own user account and asp might simply have no rights to access that ActiveX.

To fix that issue you need to ensure that ActiveX is properly installed and configured to be accessed by user account which is used to run web site on IIS.